# WooCommerce: ‘Order-pay’ page refreshes on 'submit' pay, nonce problem?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I customised the WooCommerce ‘order-pay’ page with a billing form and Ajax user creation + login functions. This all works well. The only weird thing is, when i press the ‘Order Pay’ button, the page first refreshes, so then I must press the 'Pay' button again to proceed to the payment gateway.

Any idea why it refreshes? And how i can remove this.. Thanks!

Code used:

Create user:

```
$user_id = wc_create_new_customer( $userdata['email'], $userdata['company'], $userdata['password'] );
```

Sign in:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );
if( $user ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id );
    do_action( 'wp_login', $user->user_login, $user );
}
```

Also tried:

```
$info = array();
$info['user_login']     = $userdata['email'];
$info['user_password']  = $userdata['password'];
$info['remember']       = true;

$user_signon = wp_signon( $info, true );
if ( !is_wp_error($user_signon) ){

    wp_set_current_user($user_signon->ID);
    wp_set_auth_cookie($user_signon->ID);

}
```

**Additional info.**
The 'woocommerce-pay-nonce' before (submit) refresh is different than the one after refresh. But if i refresh the page manually the nonce stays the same. So this might be a clue?

`<input type="hidden" id="woocommerce-pay-nonce" name="woocommerce-pay-nonce" value="2d17233aa9">`

BUT! `$_POST['woocommerce-pay-nonce']` = bbd0d20f38

I added the function + action mentioned in this question, but no success yet: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/184055/188144

**UPDATE.**
It is also not a payment plugin / gateway problem as i tried Stripe and Mollie.